# Can't access Gunicorn server from Google Cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn, wsgi

Pretty much the title. I'm trying to set up a simple WSGI server on Google Cloud VC but I simply can't access it from my machine: it just times out.

```
*@*:~/*$ python3 -m gunicorn app:app port --bind :6942 
[2023-08-13 10:07:57 +0000] [7700] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-08-13 10:07:57 +0000] [7700] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:6942 (7700)
[2023-08-13 10:07:57 +0000] [7700] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-08-13 10:07:57 +0000] [7702] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7702
```

This is my startup command and the log that follows: it seems to start as normal.
I've never had to do anything special to host a server on GC, aside from clicking allows HTTP/S on the VM creation screen.

I've tried different ports too.

--

For me to be able to access my server hosted in Google Cloud, which obviously didn't work which the connection timing out.

Comment: Also I'n not sure if it changes anything, but if I use the IP it just times out, but via my Cloudflare domain, it instantly gets 521-ed.

Comment: 1) How are you accessing the instance (exact URL)? 2) What are the VPC firewall rules? Edit your post with more details.

Comment: Did you try if the endpoint answer when you are connected on the VM? with localhost IP and private VM IP?

Comment: I'm using the external IP from the GC console, and I've set up a rule to allow all traffic from 0.0.0.0/0 for all ports: [(sorry for terrible quality)](https://files.catbox.moe/2wb96f.jpeg) @JohnHanley

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I'm not sure what you mean, can you elaborate?

Comment: Connection timeout out means there is nothing listening where you are connecting OR something is blocking a connection. SSH into the VM and make sure that your process is listening on the configured port. I asked what URL you are using to connect. You did not provide that information. Use CLI commands like `curl -v http://example.com:PORT/path` to debug HTTP problems.

Comment: @JohnHanley I was just a little sceptical about giving the IP. I here's the log:

`*   Trying 35.201.30.202:8000...
* connect to 35.201.30.202 port 8000 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 35.201.30.202 port 8000 after 75 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 35.201.30.202 port 8000 after 75 ms: Couldn't connect to serve`

Comment: Please add details in your question, not via comments. Always show the command and error/message. You configured gunicorn on port 6942 but your curl command is connecting on port 8000.